# 'Lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para' - Is it possible to drop 'lo' and 'como para'?

Tags: gramática, clíticos

I've just come across `lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para hacer algo` as in:

> ¿Es lo bastante inteligente como para trabajar en Google?

Is it possible and correct to say just:

> ¿Es bastante inteligente para trabajar en Google?

I've been using the second variant pretty much the whole time, maybe incorrectly.

Comment: Your variant is understandable but not beautiful; however, I could imagine a native Spanish speaker whose Spanish has been somewhat contaminated by living in an English speaking country expressing himself this way.

Comment: For the record, a Brazilian or Portuguese would express himself in the same way because the Portuguese equivalent sentence has no "como".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question asks for several alternative forms. From the start I'd say that the versions with *suficientemente* are all correct, whether they use *lo* and/or *como*:

- *¿Es lo suficientemente inteligente como para trabajar en Google?*
- *¿Es suficientemente inteligente como para trabajar en Google?*
- *¿Es lo suficientemente inteligente para trabajar en Google?*
- *¿Es suficientemente inteligente para trabajar en Google?*

In the case of *bastante* followed by an adjective, on the contrary, not using *como* sounds incorrect to me, but I haven't been able to find a proper source. (Note that *bastante*, when it functions as an adjective, does not need *como*.) The same goes for using *lo*. So I would say:

> *¿Es lo bastante inteligente como para trabajar en Google?*

With *bastante* there's a small problem: *bastante* sometimes connotes an opposition in the same way as *muy/mucho* or *demasiado*, because its meaning can vary from *just enough* to *quite a lot*.

> *Es bastante mayor como para ir sola al colegio.*
> "She's old enough to go to school by herself."
>
> *Es bastante mayor como para tener que llevarla al colegio.*
> "She's rather old for (someone) having to take her to school."

This doesn't happen if you use *lo*, since *lo bastante* always means "the amount which is enough" (the positive connotation of *bastante*); it cannot be used to mean "rather, a bit too much, enough and more".

Using *bastante* + adjective, without *lo*, in a question, sounds distinctively off to me, but again, I don't have a source for that, just my experience (as a native speaker among other native speakers).

Comment: What does the article "lo" in "Es lo bastante inteligente como para trabajar en Google?" refer to? In general, the article "lo" refers to some abstract entity and is translated to English as "what is" or "the thing", eg "Lo raro es que..." (= What is strange is that... / The strange thing is that...), but I'm unable to see that meaning here.

Comment: I don't know. I suspect it might be analyzed as *lo bastante* = "(the thing) which is enough" (since the verb *bastar* lit. means "to be enough", and *bastante* is originally its active participle).