# "como para hacer algo" vs "para hacer algo"

Tags: preposiciones

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> España queda muy lejos como para proteger nuestros intereses. (= Spain is too far away to protect our interests)

Is there any difference in meaning between "como para proteger" and "para proteger" in this sentence?

I see a similar question about "suficientemente/bastante [adjective] + como para" at ['Lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para' - Is it possible to drop 'lo' and 'como para'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/lo-bastante-suficientemente-adjetivo-como-para-is-it-possible-to-drop-l) , but I am not sure if the same reasoning applies to this sentence with "muy" instead of "suficientemente"/"bastante".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Lo bastante/suficientemente + adjetivo + como para' - Is it possible to drop 'lo' and 'como para'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/lo-bastante-suficientemente-adjetivo-como-para-is-it-possible-to-drop-l) // If not, you now have enough rep to place a bounty on the other question, if you feel the existing answer isn't clear enough, or isn't generalizable enough.  Or you could edit this question, acknowledge and link to the possible duplicate, and explain where you get stuck in trying to apply the material there to your situation.

Comment: There are several ways to try to avoid asking duplicate questions. (1) google, (2) use the built-in search bar, and (3) start typing your title and body of question, and then check the right-hand sidebar's list of related questions.  These techniques sometimes produce different results. // I hope you will continue to include season, episode and time stamp, as you kindly did on a recent question.  It's a good habit to get into.